# Prove that for every set of functions $f_i$ from N to N there is $g>^*f_i$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Prove that for every set $\lbrace f_i : i \in \Bbb N\rbrace \subseteq {\Bbb N}^{\Bbb N}$. there is $g\in{\Bbb N}^{\Bbb N}$ such that $f_i<^*g$

Definition of $<^*$ :

$f<^*g\iff \exists _n \forall_{m>n} \ f(m)<g(m)$

Can someone Help with guidance ?

Comment: Have you tried diagonalization?

Comment: Yes I did but couldn't figure our how to find that $m$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Cantor's diagonalization method. To define $f(n)$, instead of just ensuring that it is different from $f_n(n)$, try to think of a way that instead gives you a value which is larger than $f_i(n)$, for $i\leq n$.

Comment: That is what I was thinking about. But let us say that $f_i(n)=k$ so I define g(n)=k+1.  If $f_{i+1}(n+1)<k $ then $g(n+1)<k$ so from that specific $n$ it is not true that $f_i<^*g$ .
 
What am I missing?

Comment: If you have five numbers, how can you pick a number which will certainly be larger than all five numbers?

Comment: Take the sum of them?

Comment: For example (although, adding $1$ is advised, in case all of the numbers are $0$).

Comment: Can I say that $g(n)=f_1(n)+...+f_n(n)+1$?

Comment: Yes. Of course.

Comment: But then it can be the case that $g(n+1)<f_n(n+1)$

Comment: Why? What would be $g(n+1)$ according to your suggestion?

Comment: Couldn't find any. So basically for every $m$ we have $g$ so that $g(m)>f_m(m)$. so eventually we will have one for every $f_i$ right?

Comment: Just plug "$n+1$" into the definition you made *two comments earlier*. Then tell me whether or not $g(n+1)\leq f_n(n+1)$ is even possible.

Comment: You are right that's why I corrected myself, it isn't possible.